# SolvePnP - pose estimation for planar object - ambiguous case

Tags: opencv, 3d, computer-vision

I have an asymmetric circular dot pattern similar to [this](http://robocraft.ru/files/opencv/acircles_pattern.png).
I use opencv `solvePnP` function to estimate the pose of the pattern based on a) known 3D pattern point; b) detected pattern points in 2D image

I found that in some cases (when the pattern frontally face to the camera and tilted a bit), the estimated pose returned by the `solvePnP` function is unstable. There are two results for almost same pattern pose (no moving). I guess it is due to ambiguous planar poses have same 2D projection.

Is there any solution to it except the temporal filtering as suggested here:
[Similar issue](http://answers.opencv.org/question/11915/solvepnp-similar-input-returns-very-different-output/)

**Update**:
I tried to apply this [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.89.6052&rep=rep1&type=pdf) which solve the ambiguous case but it didn't work.
The code I used is from [here](http://nghiaho.com/?page_id=576).
I could get almost same result as the `cv::solvePNP` by using the algorithm, but the unstable case still exist.

Comment: If you know the scene to be planar, why not use `findHomography` ?

Comment: @Photon Sorry, I may misunderstand you. I need a 3D pose of the plane object. But the `findHomography` returns a perspective transformation H between the source and the destination planes. H is a 3x3 matrix and I assume it is 2D homography?

Comment: The image link directs to a 404. Was [this](http://robocraft.ru/files/opencv/acircles_pattern.png) the image you linked to?

Comment: @m00am thank you, link updated.

Comment: How did you end up solving this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can set to **true** the setting *useExtrinsicGuess* of solvePnP function; with this parameter, solvePnP uses the last computed pose in the first iteration of the solver inside solvePnP, see [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg–Marquardt_algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm).
For example:

```
void getPose(cv::Mat& t_vec, cv::Mat& r_vec)
{
    static cv::Mat raux, taux;
    static bool useExtrinsicGuess = false
    cv::Mat objPoints  (4, 3, CV_32FC1); // Your 3d points
    cv::Mat imagePoints(4, 2, CV_32FC1); // Your 2d points

    cv::solvePnP (objPoints, 
                  imagePoints, 
                  camera.getCameraMatrix(), // Camera matrix
                  camera.getDistorsion(),   // Camera distorsion
                  raux, taux, useExtrinsicGuess, CV_ITERATIVE);
    if (!useExtrinsicGuess) {
        useExtrinsicGuess = true;
    }
    raux.convertTo(r_vec, CV_32F);
    taux.convertTo(t_vec, CV_32F);
}
```

Also you could use more points, in different planes.

Comment: I have actually tried this, but if it is an ambiguous pose, even if I start with a correct pose, it will converge to a wrong one after LM optimisation since the reprojection error might be slightly smaller. Use more points in different planes would solve the issue since the pose is not ambiguous anymore.

Comment: I obtained better results using _solvePnPRansac_ instead of _solvePnP_  and _CV_P3P_ instead of _CV_ITERATIVE_. Let me know if with these mods will increase the pose estimation accuracy.

Comment: Better you mean accuracy or robustness?

Comment: Sorry, I meant a better robustness to the pose switch. With this configuration I have only sporadic switches a very high distances and high camera inclinations; I use a four corner marker. Hope it helps. Obviously, the rare times that the pose switch, the only solutions is to break the pose iteration and reset _useExtrinsicGuess_ to false.

Answer (score 1):

As has been already suggested, use `findHomography`, then decompose the result. See Zengyou Zhang's [paper here](http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~elgammal/classes/cs534/lectures/CameraCalibration-book-chapter.pdf). See, in particular, equations 2.18 for the concept, and 2.26 for the solution - the case you want is the one with one image only.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I checked the source code of `cv::solvePnP` which actually uses the method mentioned in the paper to solve the extrinsic parameters (i.e. pose). In addition, they also add an iterative process to refine the pose. Please see `cvFindExtrinsicCameraParams2` in [calibration.cpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/calib3d/src/calibration.cpp)